# How can i map position between CaretPosition and text in RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I need to map position in the text and current caret position in `RichTextBox`

The text I get like:

```
new TextRange(rtbContent.Document.ContentStart, rtbContent.Document.ContentEnd).Text
```

... e.g. position like this refers to incorrect char in text:

```
(new TextRange(rtbContent.Document.ContentStart, rtbContent.Document.ContentEnd)).Start.GetOffsetToPosition(rtbContent.CaretPosition))
```

E.g. i have text in RichTextBox:
"War and Peace is a novel by the Russian author Leo Tolstoy, first published in 1869".

The caret cursor is on the first char in the world "Tolstoy" ("T"). How can i get the position os the same char only in string with the same text?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you are trying to do?

Comment: On the other hand, i need to set the caret after word "novel"